# Stubbing is not covering my method in unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, stubbing

I am trying to implementing unit testing by using the stubbing methodology. 
However, when I stub the method, there is no line coverage of the tested class.

Service Class

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private Client client;

    private String doclinkUrl = "www.website.com"

    public byte[] downloadContent(String objectId) {
        String url = doclinkUrl + "documents/" +objectId + "/binary";
        return client.target(url).request().get(byte[].class);
    }
}
```

Stubbed Service Class

```
public class ServiceStub extends Service {

    @Override
    public byte[] downloadContent(String objectId) {
        return "test".getBytes();
    }

}
```

Testing Service Class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Service testee;

    @Test
    public void testDownloadContent(){
        testee = new ServiceStub();
        Assert.assertNotNull(testee.downloadContent("objectId"));
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using `spring-boot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subbing in unit testing refers to dependencies that you don't want it to interfere when you unit test a component.
Indeed you want to unit test a component behavior and mock or stub the dependency that could have side effects on it.
Here you stub the class under test. It makes no sense.

> However, when I stub the method, there is no line coverage of the
>   tested class.

Executing a test where a `ServiceStub` instance is used will not cover in terms of unit test the `Service` code of course.

In the `Service` class the dependency that you want to isolate is     :

```
@Autowired
private Client client;
```

So you could mock or stub it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the spring boot you can do an integration testing most of the part and only mocking the external API calls using `@MockBean`

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {

@Autowired
private Service service;

@MockBean
 private Client client;

@Test
public void testDownloadContent(){

    //given(this.client.ArgumentMatchers.any(url) //addtional matchers).willReturn(//somebytes);
    service = new ServiceStub();
    Assert.assertNotNull(testee.downloadContent("objectId"));
    }

 }
```